# ERROR [PortletBagFactory:123] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet

Tags: liferay

After upgrading from Liferay 6.0.6 to 6.1 and Tomcat 6 to 7, when running the build.xml file, I get the following error. I have checked liferay forums, but no help. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

```
07:26:07,593 ERROR [PortletBagFactory:123] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(PortletHotDeployListener.java:524)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:302)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:188)
```

Answer (score 2):

`com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet` is a class in the `portal-impl.jar`. It seems you are using this class in your custom plugin portlet.

Any class from `portal-impl.jar` is not recommended to be used in plugin-portlets and starting from 6.1 they have completely restricted the usage of classes from `portal-impl.jar` and here is the verdict from Liferay-staff in a [forum post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6951725#_19_message_7045789).

So I guess you are out-of-luck here and you better refrain from using `StrutsPortlet` or any of the class from `portal-impl.jar`, you will need to find another way to achieve what you already did using this class. It will be a development effort but will help with future releases and best practices.

Here is a [link](http://liferaycms.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/why-i-cant-use-portal-impl-in-my-portlet/) to understand as to why not to use `portal-impl.jar`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prakash. I will see what I can do and hopefully come back with a solution:)

Comment: I have one custom portlet and one theme. I just run the build.xml file under the portlet and I didn't get any error. But when ever I run the build.xml under the theme, then I get the problem. So doesn't this mean that the problem is not from my custom portlet, or what?

Comment: do you have `portal-impl.jar` in your build-path for your theme or portlet? or inside the `WEB-INF/lib` for the theme or portlet?

Comment: The only place I have portal-impl.jar is on this path: tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: This is strange. You mean to say that your portlet deploys ok but the theme doesn't? Have you tried creating a new portlet and theme and tried if that works? Have you check all the xml files or other things where you could have specified some dependency on some class from `portal-impl.jar`? Hope you are pointing to the correct Plugins SDK i.e. SDK for Liferay 6.1. Thanks

Comment: Despite the error, both the portlet and theme deploy, but those exceptions prevent me from creating new pages through the Control Panel. So when I want to create a new page, I get the error "/html/portal/render_portlet.jsp not found" which is most probably caused by the above mentioned exceptions. e.g. the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet" is thrown when running the build.xml under the theme. For the portlet, this line is found in WEB-INF/portlet.xml but for the theme inside WEB-INF/portlet-custom.xml. And I am using sdk-6.1.10.

Comment: I have done the portlets after the upgrade, that is in Liferay 6.1, while the theme is done before the upgrade with Liferay 6.0.6 and then migrated to 6.1.

Comment: Have you created an ext-plugin on this server? If yes then that may have screwed up the bundle, try on a clean bundle.

Comment: I haven't created any EXT plugins. By the way, I also get some other warnings saying that "Portlet with the name 165_WAR_MY-theme is described in portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in liferay-portlet.xml". OR "Portlet with the name 120_WAR_MY-theme is described in liferay-portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in portlet.xml". Could it be that I have some references or misreferences somewhere in my .xml files?

Comment: Could be. It would help if you can paste your xml configuration in the question for the theme and portlet both. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Parakash. Just like you said in your answer, I think the problem is that StrutsPortlet class. I need to do some more work about that. I will get back to you once I have got an answer to this. Thanks again.